# ASP.NET Unable to use custom Window group as a Role

Tags: asp.net, authentication, active-directory, authorization, windows-authentication

I want to use a local group to restrict access to an ASP.NET web application to local users.

I've created a Windows group (TestLocalGroup) and Windows user accounts and assigned them all to the new group.  The group and accounts are on the IIS7 web server.

In my web.config, I can properly restrict access to specific users by defining the following settings...

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>                   
  <allow users=".\TestLocalUser1,.\TestLocalUser2" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

But I can't seem to get it to work for the group.  This code won't allow my group members access...

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<authorization>                   
  <allow roles=".\TestLocalGroup" />
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

I don't have any "roleManager" section.  Do I need that?

Am I missing something?  It seems like it should just work.

Comment: Did you logoff and back on after adding your users to the group before testing?

Comment: @mellamokb: Yes, I logged my client connection to the server off.

Comment: From what I know, it should just work as well.  Can you verify by some other method that the group membership is correct?  Like setup permissions to a folder on the server and try to add / remove files.

Comment: @mellamokb:  I have the same problem if I place the users in the local Administrators group and then use <allow roles=".\Administrators" /> .  Am I missing some sort of local group syntax?

Comment: Try changing <allow roles=".\TestLocalGroup"/> to <allow roles="TestLocalGroup"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two problems.

1) It turns out that I had a different roleManager enabled on a parent web.config.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleManager">...
```

For my site I had to clear the roleManager to get the windows roles to work again.

```
<roleManager enabled="false" />
```

2) As I was adding my users to the groups, there didn't appear to be any immediate effect.  I logged on and off as suggested by mellamokb (Thank you!).  That didn't make any difference, but it did point me to the correct solution; recycling my web site.  I assume there is some timed credential cache and recycling the web site will clear it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,,, I have to delete roleManager... from my web.config.